# Google Compute Engine Managed Groups - not enough instances started

Tags: google-compute-engine

Just a sanity check but on GCE if i have "Minimum number of instances" set to 3 for an Instance group i should have 3 running instances?

Seems i get 2 running and 1 additional shown as offline under the groups instances.

I increased it to 4 and the same story, 2 running and 2 offline?

I did wait a while but nothing changes.

I have been provisioning using just the portal and not command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are telling me, it seems that it could be that you are passing your quota for CPUs. The default is 24 CPUs. I tried to create an instance group for 4 VMs of 16 cores each and only 1 was running while the other ones appeared with the red circle next to it.

To see what your limits are you can go to Quotas on the left under Compute Engine in the Developers Console. If you need more you can fill out the form on this site at the bottom.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/resource-quotas

Hope this clarifies everything for you.

Comment: Thanks Vaqar, thats it. I have 8 of 8 cpus on west euro instance on the trial account. Ill try spreading things about a bit.